# Read the value of a UILabel in Automation template of Instruments in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I have written the following script to tap on a button on UI. Each press increments the integer value of a UILabel. I wish to read the value of the UILabel in my script. How can I achieve this? I am new to this Automation tool in Instruments.

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var appName = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().name;
target.setDeviceOrientation(UIA_DEVICE_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["Increment"].tap();
```

Comment: Can't help you with your problem directly. But if you are doing this for testing, I would suggest trying out the new UI testing frame which which is part of Apple's XCTest. You might find it much easier to use than the older UI Automation stuff.

Comment: I thought XCTest is for Unit Testing. I didn't know you could do UI testing with XCTest.

Comment: XCTest has been significantly enhanced with support for launching apps and interrogating their interfaces. Having now used it on a project, I think it's rather similar to the way I would write tests in Frank or Calabash, but without the Cucumber BDD front end. There is still a fair amount of features that Apple could pack into it. But generally speaking I would say it's a viable option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure you assign accessibility identifier to that UILabel.

You can do that via code:

```
self.myLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = @"uniqueId";
```

Or via storyBoard:

[image]

To get label value, use the following line in your UIAutomation script:

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().staticTexts()["uniqueId"].value();
```